# Dijkstra's algorithm java implementation bug

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, priority-queue, dijkstra

So first of all this is HW, so try not to just give me the answer right away, but I'm having trouble programming Dijstra's Algorithm. The lab has us build a priority Queue, which I have made and passes the given JUnit tests so I think it's correct. The second part of the lab had us use the queue in an implementation of dijstra's algorithm. Here is my code for Dijkstra's

```
/**
 * Compute shortest paths in a graph.
 *
 * Your constructor should compute the actual shortest paths and
 * maintain all the information needed to reconstruct them.  The
 * returnPath() function should use this information to return the
 * appropriate path of edge ID's from the start to the given end.
 *
 * Note that the start and end ID's should be mapped to vertices using
 * the graph's get() function.
 */

class ShortestPaths {

    Multigraph graph;
    final int INF = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    PriorityQueue<Integer> Q;
    int n;
    int dist[];
    Handle handles[];
    Edge edge[];

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public ShortestPaths(Multigraph G, int startId) {
        Q = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
        graph = G;
        n = graph.nVertices();
        dist = new int [n];
        edge = new Edge [n];
        handles = new Handle[n];

        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
            dist[i] = INF;
        }
        dist[startId] = 0;

        Handle h = Q.insert(startId, dist[startId]);
        handles[startId] = h;   
        Q = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
        while (!Q.isEmpty()){
            Vertex v = graph.get(Q.min());
            Q.extractMin();
            while (v.adj().hasNext()){
                relax(v.adj().next());  
            }       
        }   
    }

    private void relax(Edge e) {
        Handle h;
        int v = e.from().id();
        int w = e.to().id();
        if (dist[w] > dist[v] + e.weight()) {
            dist[w] = dist[v] + e.weight();
            edge[w] = e;
            if (handles[w].getIndex() != -1){
                Q.decreaseKey(handles[w], dist[w]);
            }
            else{
                h = Q.insert(w, dist[w]);
                handles[w] = h;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the list of edge ID's forming a shortest path from the start
     * vertex to the specified end vertex.
     *
     * @return the array
     */
    public int[] returnPath(int endId) {
        int c = 0;
        int[] path = new int[edge.length];
        for (Edge e = edge[endId]; e != null; e = edge[e.from().id()]) {
            path[c] = e.id();
            c++;
        }
        return path;
    }


}
```

Just so you know, a handle is simply an object which stores the index of the associated key-value pair, that way we can find it later. The handles update automatically, you can see this in the swap procedure in my priority queue. Anyway, The issue is that my edge[] array is populated with null for some reason, so I can't return any paths. How do I fix my algorithm to update edge[] correctly? Any help would be appreciated. Just tell me if you would like more information. Also I will post the Vertex and Edge classes in case you want to look at those.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I guess why is my edge[] array null, and how can I fix it, sorry didn't make that clear let me edit my post

Comment: There is tons of code here that no one is going to read. Try to make your question specific, and show only the relevant part of code, preferably not more than 10-15 lines of code where you believe the error is. You should also format the question so the actual question is at the very first or at the very last of the thread, and not hidden in the middle.

Comment: Where do you add your edges to your edge array?  I see the array definition, but not where you add the edges to the array

Comment: okay let me update my post

Comment: Also, you mention that you are using (probably forced by the homework description) a queue developed that you... I would try first implementing Djikstra using `java.util.Queue` and only swap to your implementation once it works (and test again). Just to isolate the issues.

Comment: that's a good idea let me try that, thanks.

Comment: Careful, the java implementation of `PriorityQueue` does __not__ support the decrease key operation, so it's pretty much useless for Dijkstra.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed one error:

```
Q = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
while (!Q.isEmpty()){ // <-- Q is always empty beсause of previous line
```

Comment: Aww yes stupid mistake. Thanks. Unfortunately now I'm getting a null pointer in my handles array. on line 61 here `if(handles[w].getIndex() != -1)`

Comment: You can try to change `if` condition to `if (handles[w] != null && handles[w].getIndex() != -1){`. Its possible that 'w' not in the Q at that moment.

Comment: hmmm, that's interesting. What you're saying makes sense but that change in the code spawned an infinite loop. The nested while loop to be more specefic

Comment: It could be problem with iteration over vertices. You can try this: `Vertex k=v.adj();
while(k.hasNext()) {
relax(k);
k=k.next();
}`

Comment: well adj() actually returns an iterator for edges so that wouldn't work. Sorry should have specified that. I can add the code for the vertex class if you want

Comment: Ok, than you need to store iterator in some variable: `Iterator<Vertex> it=v.adj(); while (it.hasNext()) {...}`

Comment: Alright I did what you suggested. My code: `EdgeIterator it=v.adj();Edge k = it.next();while (it.hasNext()){relax(k);k = it.next();}` Anyway, now my algorithm is either just not returning the correct path, or I will get an out of bounds exception (-2147483648) on this line of code `Vertex v = graph.get(Q.min());` Honestly all this is probably beyond the scope of my original question and this is turning into a bug hunt, so don't feel like you need to keep helping me.